# llamada de datos

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

a ver buenos días, una duda que no sé porque me sale. yo he creado un dashboard para alojar las noticias que voy a utilizar en una web pero tengo un problemilla, yo copio el texto en el textarea y me lo guarda con espacios(como lo necesito) pero mi problema está cuando lo llamo en la web con php que al imprimirlo pues me lo pone como un string completo y los espacios desaparecen y no se como hacerlo.
a alguièn se le ocurre como debería hacerlo o cual es el problema a solucionar

este es el render de pintado en la web

```
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="aboutus_area wow fadeInLeft">
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['cero'])) {
                $noticia = Conexion::getNoticia0();
            }
            echo "<h2>" . $noticia["titulo"] . "</h2>";
            echo "<h3>" . $noticia["tema"] . "</h3>";
            echo "<p><span>" . $noticia["fuente"] . "</span></p>";
            echo "<p>" . $noticia["noticia"] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>" . $noticia["fecha"] . "</p>";
            ?>
            <p class='wow fadeInLeftBig animated' style='visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInLeftBig;'>Siga visitando nuestra Web. <a href='index.php'>Inicio</a></p>
        </div>
```

y así lo envío a la db

```
.
.
.
if (isset($_POST["campo_enlace"]) && $_POST["campo_enlace"] != "") {
    $enlace = filter_var($_POST["campo_enlace"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

if (isset($_POST["campo_fecha"]) && $_POST["campo_fecha"] != "") {
    $fecha = filter_var($_POST["campo_fecha"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

Conexion::setNewNoticia($tema, $titulo, $noticia, $fuente, $enlace, $fecha);
```

y la consulta q hago para coger los datos

```
public static function getNoticia($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE id=$id";
    $resultado = self::consulta($sql);
    $noticia = array();

    if ($resultado) {
        $row = $resultado->fetch();
        while ($row != null) {
            $noticia[] = $row;
            $row = $resultado->fetch();
        }
    }
    return $noticia;
}
```

Comment: Para poder ayudarte se necesita más información, incluyendo parte del código implicado. Puedes mirar estos enlaces para ver cómo funciona el sitio: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve y https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Con esto pinto en la web lo que traigo

Comment: No me queda claro del todo el problema pero intuyo que no te respeta los saltos de línea. Prueba a aplicar la función `nl2br()` al texto de la noticia.   http://php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php

Comment: ¿Los datos están guardados con espacio? ¿Qué tipo de espacio?